# generating json from csv file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, csv

I need to read a CSV file containing huge data and transform it into a JSON Object. I have written this code but the JSON Objects generated are having some error in it and is not according to my expectations.

```
def readFromFile(fileName)

        jsonFile = File.open('some.json','w')

         CSV.foreach(fileName,:headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row| 
         $jsonData['Email'] = {
              :subject => row[0],
              :body => row[1],
              :fromName => row[2],
              :fromEmail => row[3],
              :toName => row[5],
              :toEmail => row[6]
          }
          # puts "data is #{jsonData[jsonData.length-1]}"

          jsonFile.write(JSON.pretty_generate($jsonData));

         # CSV.parse(row).to_json
         # @jsonFile.write(JSON.pretty_generate(@jsonData));
       #   csv = CSV.new(fileName, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all)
        #  csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
    end
```

Comment: What is the error? Could you post it.

Comment: it got fixed..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will help you ( I get it from http://jasonheppler.org/2014/07/12/parsing-csv-to-json/ ):

```
def readFromFile(fileName)
  def is_int(str)
    # Check if a string should be an integer
    return !!(str =~ /^[-+]?[1-9]([0-9]*)?$/)
  end

  lines = CSV.open(filename).readlines
  keys = lines.delete lines.first

  File.open('some.json', "w") do |f|
    data = lines.map do |values|
      is_int(values) ? values.to_i : values.to_s
      Hash[keys.zip(values)]
    end
    f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(data)
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked smoothly..also could you guide me to some books which is starightforward in how to write programs in ruby using classes(similar to java) and regular expressions(RegEx in ruby)

Comment: I like Eloquent Ruby by Russ Olsen

Comment: Please check the answer if it helps u. :P

Comment: Yeah, there is a check with a 0 and one up row and one down row. Will be great if you click there ;-)